# c# Minimalistic Telnet how to receive long string response from the server

Tags: c#, telnet

I use this Telnet Library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library

I converted the c# console program from that link into C# Winform program. I am able to send data to my device (microcontroller, to be specific) and I'm actually done in this part. The problem is that how am I suppose to read the device/server's response?

If you're gonna open the link and read some part of the code how to use the library, it shows here how to send data to the server and read a data from the server.

```
// while connected
while (tc.IsConnected && prompt.Trim() != "exit" )
{
// display server output
Console.Write(tc.Read());

// send client input to server
prompt = Console.ReadLine();
tc.WriteLine(prompt);

// display server output
Console.Write(tc.Read());
}
```

I use WriteLine in sending data to the device, as I've said, I'm done with this. I just don't know where to put the tc.Read(); part in my winform program.

The device is send this long string with a length of 89 continuously and quite fast!

***sensor1: 0.10meters sensor2: 1.51meters sensor3: 2.03meters sensor4: 1.7meters temp: 21degC***

By the way, I will put each values to the specific labels. So here's my code in getting the values using substring:

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //"Sensor1: 0.00meters Sensor2: 0.00meters Sensor3: 0.00meters Sensor4: 0.00meters 21.00degC"
        if (connectedChecker1 == true)
        {
            dataReceived = tc.Read();
            if (dataReceived.Length == 89)
            {
                tempVal.Text = (str1.Substring(80, 5)) + "°C";
                frontVal.Text = str1.Substring(9, 10);
                leftVal.Text = str1.Substring(29, 10);
                backVal.Text = str1.Substring(49, 10);
                rightVal.Text = str1.Substring(69, 10);
                dataReceived = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

lol, forgive me, I really don't know where to put this part. I'm counting the length of the received data but what if there is this delay happen during the communication and the C# program reads the response as:

***gCsensor1: 0.10meters sensor2: 1.51meters sensor3: 2.03meters sensor4: 1.7meters temp: 21deg***

I'm now thinking to put a while loop in a button used for connecting:

```
    private void vesselBoardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ethernetIP.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(servoUnoIp.ToString());
        try
        {
            //create a new telnet connection for MEGA
           tc = new TelnetConnection(ethernetIP, 23);
            if (tc.IsConnected)
              connectedChecker1 = true;

            //create a new telnet connection for Uno
           unoTc = new TelnetConnection(servoUnoIp, 23);
           if (unoTc.IsConnected)
             connectedChecker = true;

           statusLbl.Text = "Connected";

//INSERT WHILE LOOP HERE FOR RECEIVING DATA....

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check the ip address of the boards");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: ah sorry. Question is: Where should I put the receiving part? How to receive server's response?